# Facebook October 2013 breaking changes - webview login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

In https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/

"Native iOS or Android apps initiating their own web views for Facebook login are required to use our official SDKs for login by October 2, 2013. Native iOS or Android apps using third-party SDKs that provide Facebook login via custom web views have an extension until January 8, 2014 to work with their third-party provider to resolve this or to migrate to our SDKs."

I'm using the Facebook SDK without single sign on.

Will the changes be effective from October 2, 2013 or January 8, 2014?
What are exactly 'third-party SDKs'?

Comment: If you use the official Facebook SDK, then you should be fine. This is referring to apps that roll with their own web views, or apps that use SDKs that talk to Facebook, but is not the official Facebook SDK.

Comment: Thanks, looks like we weren't affected